# Java timer working weird/not working

Tags: java, timer

So I'm making a game and I need a timer to regend/deregen stamina from the player.
Here's my current code:

```
Timer staminaTimer = new Timer(); //Java.util timer
    public void update() {

    staminaTimer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

        public void run() {

            //regen/Deregen stamina

        }

    }, 0L, 10L * 1000L);
}
```

So this timer is in an method that is getting called every game tick. I don't know why but if I put a print in the run() its starts normally then becomes really fasts and crashes everything. I would really like to know another way of making a repeating timer or the fix of this... Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Assuming you're game has a "main" loop, you should be calculating the progress there (or allowing the entity to do it), introducing more times is not accurate of efficent

Comment: Yeah, using a timer for this kind of thing seems like a bad idea. That being said, what is happening is really weird unless you call `update()` many times and end up with a lot of spamming timers, so you might want to add another print in the `update()` function and see what happens.

Comment: When I put a print there it spamms console.

Comment: Based on your symptoms, it sounds like you're creating multiple timers or multiple tasks. Put some debugging statements outside of your timer init to easily watch for this.